# No EU citizen with UK EEA issued not expired visa living in non EU country need UK visa for visit?

Tags: uk

it is a particular situation, I am a non EU citizen with a non expired EEA visa issued in the UK where lived with my EU citizen wife for 2 years; for work reasons we moved to the middle east and we are traveling to UK for tourism soon, does the EEA not expired visa still valid even when I've been living for 3 years in the middle east? . Travelling to the UK with the whole EU citizens family, I'm the only non EU citizen. Agin the UK EEA visa hasn't expired still has 2 more years to expire.

Comment: There's no "EEA visa" as far as I'm aware.  The *EEA family permit* is issued for six months.  Is your document a residence card?  What exactly is it?

Comment: Yes, my document is a EEA residence card valid for 5 years as EU family member.

Answer (score 1):

If you are travelling with your EU citizen spouse and with a valid EEA residence card you do not need a visa to enter the UK as your spouse would be exercising treaty rights: https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply, my concern now is if the residence card is still valid as we left the UK 3 years ago and don't know if any rule aplies on these cases